# Parquet file bq load is failing with Resources exceeded during query execution: UDF out of memory. error

Tags: google-bigquery, parquet, bq

I am trying to load a parquet file to bigquery using bq comand line utility with option --parquet_enable_list_inference=true. I have confirmed that the number of columns is less than 20 in the file and the row size is not more than 50 mb, maximum it will be 30KB.

When I try to load the same parquet file with option
--parquet_enable_list_inference=false load was succesfull. But when the option is enabled it is failing with following error :

*Resources exceeded during query execution: UDF out of memory.; Failed to
read Parquet file /bigstore/file.parquet. This might happen if the file contains a
row that is too large, or if the total size of the pages loaded for the queried columns is too large.*

Command used to load :

```
bq load --replace --source_format=PARQUET --parquet_enable_list_inference=true  ted_analysis.test_table gs://tmp-usage/test.parquet
```

*bq Version - BigQuery CLI 2.0.75*